# Way to detect which component is clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, assign, interaction

In my jsx page I have two identical search input components used to filter both company and users data. Is there a way to detect which button has been pressed using React?

```
<SearchInput label={'Cerca Azienda'} company={company} users={users} setSearchResults={setSearchResults} />

<SearchInput label={'Cerca Utente'} company={company} users={users} setSearchResults={setSearchResults} />
```

Comment: can you use the `onClick`  function and pass the variable to see which on is clicked on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, that is not really possible. However, I'd like to propose an alternative method - a function which returns another function:

```js
const setSearchResults = (name) => {
    return () => {
        console.log('Setting search results for company', name)
    }
}
```

Then, you can simply use it like this:

```
<SearchInput label={'Cerca Azienda'} company={company} users={users} setSearchResults={setSearchResults('Cerca Azienda')} />

<SearchInput label={'Cerca Utente'} company={company} users={users} setSearchResults={setSearchResults('Cerca Utente')} />
```